# Help, what does Ignoring file name 'Untitled Document 1' in a directory when installing Java mean?

Tags: installation, 13.10, java

I am trying to install Java on Ubuntu 13.10 and I keep getting this error...

"Ignoring file 'Untitled Document 1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension"

ALL I WANT TO DO IS INSTALL JAVA so I can play Pogo games on my laptop. I have Google Chrome, Chromimium, and Firefox.

Can anybody help me, please install Java on my laptop. I am NEW to ubuntu, so I would need help on what commands, etc to do, for a newbie, lol!

Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete the file `Untitled Document 1` in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` by running the below command in terminal.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/"Untitled Document 1"
```